# How to rotate the imported picture?

Tags: delphi, pascal

[image]

I am gonna make a visual display for railway signalling. The problem is I just can't draw parallelogram shape, so I just imported it from another program. Here is the problem: I really haven't any clue how to rotate that parallelogram 45 degree to the right.Any ideas?

Comment: Stop using shapes and bitmaps and draw manually using GDI instead.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which Delphi version are you using? Are you using VCL or FMX? Are you targetting Windows? You can edit your question to add all those informations.

Comment: Given the screenshot, this is Delphi 7 (thus VCL).

Comment: As per tag I might also assist with drawing in Turbo Pascal 7.

Answer (score 1):

No need to load a picture: you can draw a paralellogram using Canvas drawing feature:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
    Points : array of TPoint;
begin
    SetLength(Points, 4);
    Points[0] := Point(10, 20);
    Points[1] := Point(30, 20);
    Points[2] := Point(40, 30);
    Points[3] := Point(20, 30);
    // Border of polygon
    Canvas.Pen.Width   := 2;
    Canvas.Pen.Color   := clYellow;
    // Interior color of polygon
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    Canvas.Polygon(Points);
end;
```

You can also draw using GDI+ which permit to do transformations such as rotate, translate, flip and more.

Here is a code sample:

```
uses Winapi.GDIPAPI, Winapi.GDIPOBJ, Winapi.GDIPUTIL;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
    Graphics  : TGPGraphics;
    GdiPen    : TGPPen;
    GdiBrush  : TGPBrush;
    GdiPoints : array of TGPPoint;
    GdiMatrix : TGPMatrix;
begin
    Graphics  := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
    GdiPen    := TGPPen.Create(GPColor(clYellow), 4);
    GdiBrush  := TGPSolidBrush.Create(GPColor(clRed));
    GdiMatrix := TGPMatrix.Create();

    SetLength(GdiPoints, 4);
    GdiPoints[0] := MakePoint(110, 20);
    GdiPoints[1] := MakePoint(150, 20);
    GdiPoints[2] := MakePoint(190, 80);
    GdiPoints[3] := MakePoint(150, 80);

    Graphics.FillPolygon(GdiBrush, PGPPoint(@GdiPoints[0]), Length(GdiPoints));
    Graphics.DrawPolygon(GdiPen,   PGPPoint(@GdiPoints[0]), Length(GdiPoints));

    GdiMatrix.RotateAt(30.0, MakePoint(110.0, 30.0));
    Graphics.SetTransform(GdiMatrix);
    GdiPen.SetWidth(1);
    GdiPen.SetColor(GPColor(clBlack));
    // This line is horizontal but it will be rotate by the transformation set
    Graphics.DrawLine(GdiPen, 110, 30, 190, 30);

    FreeAndNil(GdiMatrix);
    FreeAndNil(GdiPen);
    FreeAndNil(GdiBrush);
    FreeAndNil(Graphics);
end;
```

You can combine several transformations using TGPMatrixMultiply. For example: you create a matrix like the code above but using Translate method, then you create the rotation matrix as above and you combine both using multiply before calling SetTransform. Please note that this is not commutative! That is translate first and then rotate doesn't give the same result as rotate first and then translate.

Comment: @royyan ghozali If my answer solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted". You do that clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use vector graphics to draw geometric/amorph (filled) shapes. Just create an instance from TPalallelogramm to draw an arbitrary sized/shifted/rotated palallelogramm. It stores the calculated coords until one of its data change. So the redraw becomes faster.

The demo PAS:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TPoint2D = packed record
    case b : byte of
      0: ( x, y : double );
      1: ( coords : array [0..1] of double );
  end;

  TPalallelogramm = class
    private
      // Fields
      fLocation : TPoint2D;
      fSideSizes : TPoint2D;
      fAngle : double;
      fRotationAngle : double;
      fLineColor : cardinal;
      fFillColor : cardinal;

      // Derived fields
      fValidPoints : boolean;
      fPoints : array [0..3] of TPoint;

    protected
      // Virtual methods
      procedure validatePoints; virtual;
      function isValueChanged( const valueOld_, valueNew_ : double ) : boolean; virtual;

    public
      procedure setLocationCoordAt( ndx_ : byte; const coord_ : double );
      procedure setSideSizeAt( ndx_ : byte; const size_ : double );
      procedure setAngle( const angle_ : double );
      procedure setRotationAngle( const rotationAngle_ : double );
      procedure setLineColor( lineColor_ : cardinal );
      procedure setFillColor( fillColor_ : cardinal );
      procedure drawToCanvas( canvas_ : TCanvas );

  end;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    fPalallelogramm : TPalallelogramm;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

const
  CONST_distance_Minimum : double = 1e-5;

procedure TPalallelogramm.validatePoints;
var
  sideA, sideB : TPoint2D;

  procedure setPointAt( ndx_ : byte; const x_, y_ : double );
  var
    ppt : PPoint;
  begin
    ppt := @fPoints[ndx_];
    ppt^.x := round( fLocation.x + x_ );
    ppt^.y := round( fLocation.y + y_ );
  end;

  function rotatePoint( const x_, y_, angle_ : double ) : TPoint2D;
  var
    s, c : double;
  begin
    s := sin( angle_ );
    c := cos( angle_ );
    result.x := x_*c - y_*s;
    result.y := y_*c - x_*s;
  end;

begin
  sideA := rotatePoint( fSideSizes.x, 0, fRotationAngle );
  sideB := rotatePoint( fSideSizes.y, 0, fAngle + fRotationAngle );

  setPointAt( 0, 0, 0 );
  setPointAt( 1, sideA.x, sideA.y );
  setPointAt( 2, sideA.x + sideB.x, sideA.y + sideB.y );
  setPointAt( 3, sideB.x, sideB.y );
  fValidPoints := TRUE;
end;

function TPalallelogramm.isValueChanged( const valueOld_, valueNew_ : double ) : boolean;
begin
  result := abs( valueNew_ - valueOld_ ) > CONST_distance_Minimum;
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.setLocationCoordAt( ndx_ : byte; const coord_ : double );
begin
  if ( ndx_ < 2 ) then
  begin
    if ( isValueChanged( fLocation.coords[ndx_], coord_ ) ) then
    begin
      fLocation.coords[ndx_] := coord_;
      fValidPoints := FALSE;
    end;
  end else
    ;//raise...
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.setSideSizeAt( ndx_ : byte; const size_ : double );
begin
  if ( ndx_ < 2 ) then
  begin
    if ( isValueChanged( fSideSizes.coords[ndx_], size_ ) ) then
    begin
      fSideSizes.coords[ndx_] := size_;
      fValidPoints := FALSE;
    end;
  end else
    ;//raise...
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.setAngle( const angle_ : double );
begin
  if ( isValueChanged( fAngle, angle_ ) ) then
  begin
    fAngle := angle_;
    fValidPoints := FALSE;
  end;
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.setRotationAngle( const rotationAngle_ : double );
begin
  if ( isValueChanged( fRotationAngle, rotationAngle_ ) ) then
  begin
    fRotationAngle := rotationAngle_;
    fValidPoints := FALSE;
  end;
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.setLineColor( lineColor_ : cardinal );
begin
  fLineColor := lineColor_;
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.setFillColor( fillColor_ : cardinal );
begin
  fFillColor := fillColor_;
end;

procedure TPalallelogramm.drawToCanvas( canvas_ : TCanvas );
begin
  if ( canvas_ <> NIL ) then
  begin
    if ( not fValidPoints ) then
      validatePoints;
    canvas_.pen.style := psSolid;
    canvas_.pen.width := 1;
    canvas_.pen.color := fLineColor;

    canvas_.brush.style := bsSolid;
    canvas_.brush.color := fFillColor;

    canvas_.Polygon( fPoints );
  end else
    ;//raise...
end;


procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fPalallelogramm.drawToCanvas( canvas );
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fPalallelogramm := TPalallelogramm.Create;
  fPalallelogramm.setLocationCoordAt( 0, 500 );
  fPalallelogramm.setLocationCoordAt( 1, 500 );
  fPalallelogramm.setSideSizeAt( 0, 100 );
  fPalallelogramm.setSideSizeAt( 1, 50 );
  fPalallelogramm.setAngle( pi/3 );
  fPalallelogramm.setRotationAngle( pi/9 );
  fPalallelogramm.setLineColor( clBlue );
  fPalallelogramm.setFillColor( clYellow );
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fPalallelogramm.Free;
end;

end.
```

The demo DFM:

```
object Form3: TForm3
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form3'
  ClientHeight = 411
  ClientWidth = 852
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 8
    Top = 368
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```